# How to automatically login and start some program after computer is turned on

Tags: windows-10

Operating system is windows 10

Basically I want a certain bat file to run every time windows restart.

I look around. All I found is a way putting stuff on start up. The problem with that is that thing runs after users logged in.

Say I have a user, called admin.

I want every time the computer turns on, I want windows to automatically login as admin and then run the bat file.

Basically i want the computer to run certain program 24/7 (mining). Once in a while, the computer went down or restart by it self. Until I found out why, I want the computer to just do it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a shortcut to the .bat and then cut the shortcut.

Open the start menu and type "Run" to launch Run application and type "shell:startup" when the startup folder opens paste the shortcut here.

If your computer restarts it should launch to the login screen and this will not help your cause so you will have to bypass the login screen, to do this follow the next couple of steps.

Login to the user account you want to launch automatically and click on the start menu. Type in "netplwiz". This will open a new window showing user accounts.

Click on the user account you want to launch and then make sure the tick box is not checked. You will get prompted for the username and password for that user. Click ok and close the window then test it by restarting the machine.

Comment: I tried this, but the problem is that  if I disconnect RDP and  re-connect, I do not get any prompt to login - it just goes to the screen.  I do want the system to require credentials.  Any ideas ?

Comment: When you launch RDP does it require credentials to establish the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Change the username used for RDP connection. Deny RDP login for autologin user.

You cannot login through RDP to the local session - you must use in this case tools like TeamViewer, VNC, etc.